# What does "[[ $- != *i* ]] && return" mean?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I have this line in my `.bashrc` and I would like to know what exactly this means

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- `$-` means 'current flags'.
- `echo $-` returns "himBH". Those are all defaults.
- so ... `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` actually does what it says above in a comment: it checks if the interactive flag is set. The [[ and ]] make it a boolean so it ends up in a "true" or "false". "false && return" makes it go on "true && return" makes it execute the return.

The default flags explained in more detail:

h is for "hash all": this tells bash to remember the locations of commands it has found through querying your PATH.

i is for "interactive": entering input & getting back output.

m is for "monitor": this enables job control

B is for "brace expand". This allows you to use brace expansion

H is for "history expand". This is what enables you to rerun a command from your history by prefacing its number with an exclamation point

---

By the way. I have ...

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Basically does the same but easier to read I assume.

Answer (score 6):

Basically it means "If the shell flags don't contain a lowercase i, then stop the function/script here".

```
[[ ]]
```

denotes a conditional expression in bash

```
$-
```

means the shell flags. It will contain "i" if the shell is interactive (ie. you can type commands, as opposed to, it's executing a script)

```
!=
```

simply means "not equal to".

```
*i*
```

is a wildcard pattern that matches anything containing "i"

```
return
```

without any arguments just means stop the execution of the current function or script.

```
&&
```

is the logical *AND* operator. The expression at the right, in this case `return`, will only be evaluated (executed) if the expression at the left is *true*. So in many programming languages, `a && b` is a shorthand for `if a then b` -- this is called "short-circuit evaluation" and it drives programming teachers crazy when you use it :D

Answer (score 2):

I would assume it's like it says: if bash isn't open in an interactive shell, then don't do anything.

I don't know the whole function, but there are probably commands and flags set below that line in case you do have bash open in a TTY.

Comment: thanks :) but I am looking forward to know what exactly is `$-` and `*i*` and how does it find out whether its interactive mode or not

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257571/why-does-bashrc-check-whether-the-current-shell-is-interactive